# Centering the Nav Menu: Wordpress Hemingway Theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I am still learning CSS, and don't know PhP, so I am probably missing something simple here.

Trying to center the nav menu (ul.blog-menu) and can't seem to figure it out. Have reviewed the other threads on this topic and so far none of it worked for me.

I am using the [Hemingway Theme by Anders Noren](https://www.andersnoren.se/teman/hemingway-wordpress-theme/). Menu is offset to the left-center

The site is http://www.fredwbaker.com/

[Menu, offset to left, showing element in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB3tA.png)

The relevant code section in the stylesheet is below. THANK YOU for your insight!

```html
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* 5. Navigation
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.mobile-menu { 
 display: none; 
}

.blog-menu {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
 }

.blog-menu ul {
 margin: 0;
}

.blog-menu li { 
 line-height: 1;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.blog-menu > li + li:before {
 color: #444;
 content: "/";
 display: block;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1;
 margin: -9px 0 0 -3px;
 position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.blog-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 27px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5 );
 font-size: 13px;
}

.blog-menu a:hover,
.blog-menu .current-menu-item a { 
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.blog-menu > .menu-item-has-children a,
.blog-menu > .page_item_has_children a { padding-right: 35px; }

.blog-menu > .menu-item-has-children::after,
.blog-menu > .page_item_has_children::after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 border: 5px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5 );
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1001;
 right: 17px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -2px;
 transition: border-color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-menu > .menu-item-has-children:hover::after,
.blog-menu > .page_item_has_children:hover::after { border-top-color: #fff; }

.blog-menu li:hover a {
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.blog-menu li:hover > a { color: #fff; }


/* Sub Menus --------------------------------- */

.blog-menu ul {
 position: inline-block;
 display: none;
 z-index: 999;
 text-align: center;
}

.blog-menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
}

.blog-menu ul > .menu-item-has-children::after,
.blog-menu ul > .page_item_has_children::after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
 border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1001;
 right: 10px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -5px;
}

.blog-menu ul > .menu-item-has-children:hover::after,
.blog-menu ul > .page_item_has_children:hover::after { border-left-color: #fff; }

.blog-menu ul li {  
 width: 240px; 
 background: #1d1d1d;
}

.blog-menu ul a {
 padding: 20px 0px;
 margin: 0 20px;
 line-height: 130%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.blog-menu ul > li:last-child a { border-bottom-width: 0; }

.blog-menu li:hover > ul {
 opacity: 1;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
}


/* Deep down --------------------------------------- */


.blog-menu ul li:hover > ul {
 top: 0;
 left: 240px;
 margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you sending a url to inspect from I can't say for sure this will work but because the blog menu is using flex, try adding justify-content:center. So:

```
.blog-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Here is the link: http://www.fredwbaker.com/. So sorry I forgot to add it! The justify-content: center; didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, no problem I've just tried it on the link you've sent and its worked with no issue? Where are you adding custom CSS to?

Comment: Ok, you rock! I was adding it in the wrong spot (in the stylesheet itself). When I added it to the additional css section. Thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked! Can you upvote this answer so everyone knows its resolved? Thanks

Comment: Done. It said that votes are recorded, but don't change public status for people with sub-15 rep. I did hit the check mark. Thanks so much again!